# React Native Google Sign in ios build errors utility.h not found

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

any idea why I am getting this kind of strange errors ?

[image]
 Is it because of dependency issues ? or because of configurations in xcode project?
    any header search path etc are missing ?

here is my pod file dependency. the issue is coming inside Pods/boost-for-react-native/boost/compatibility/cpp_c_headers

interestingly all files have no file extension in that folder

```
target 'testApp' do
  rn_path = '../node_modules/react-native'
  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'

  # See http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html#configuring-cocoapods-dependencies
  pod 'yoga', path: "#{rn_path}/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga.podspec"
  pod 'React', path: rn_path, subspecs: [
    'DevSupport',
    'Core',
    'CxxBridge',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTWebSocket',
  ]

  # React Native third party dependencies podspecs
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => "#{rn_path}/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec"
  pod 'glog', :podspec => "#{rn_path}/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec"
  # If you are using React Native <0.54, you will get the following error:
  # "The name of the given podspec `GLog` doesn't match the expected one `glog`"
  # Use the following line instead:
  #pod 'GLog', :podspec => "#{rn_path}/third-party-podspecs/GLog.podspec"
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => "#{rn_path}/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec"

  # react-native-maps dependencies
  pod 'react-native-maps', path: rn_maps_path
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', path: rn_maps_path  # Remove this line if you don't want to support GoogleMaps on iOS
  pod 'GoogleMaps'  # Remove this line if you don't want to support GoogleMaps on iOS
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils' # Remove this line if you don't want to support GoogleMaps on iOS

  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'react-native-google-maps'
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES'] = 'No'
      end
    end
    if target.name == "React"
      target.remove_from_project
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I resolved this issue by doing it from beginning ( later I realised that this issue I got due to manual linking of library using react native link and using xcode pods )
1. Eject from Expo 
2. run the command sudo react-native link
3. Add google signin project to your xcode project (node_modules/react-native-google-signin/ios/RNGoogleSignin.xcodeproj )
4. Add google signin bundle GoogleSignIn.bundle to your project (node_modules/react-native-google-signin/ios/GoogleSdk/GoogleSignIn.bundle )

Answer (score 1):

We had same issue, Problem was header path in Google sign in package.

Even though we were using latest version of react-native-google-signin 0.12.0, Header Path was not set right.

There is already a merged PR fixing this issue, not sure if it is in released package/or its something with npm cache.

Link to PR https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin/pull/393/commits/100ca145924c3773d0a931ec97db992a83418356

I made these changes manually in xcode, its working now!

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin/pull/393/commits/100ca145924c3773d0a931ec97db992a83418356